# Problem in my Dictionary<Divisa,double> not using the implemented Equals(Divisa obj) of public class Divisa:IEquatable<Divisa>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a class called Divisa which extends IEquatable. This class just gots a field of type string so in my implemented Equals of IEquatable y just compare that string.

The point is: I have another class whihc contains A dictiory when I try to find an stored key it tells me that it doesn't exits.

Here is the code of ConversorDivisas:

```
public class ConversorDivisas
{
    private Divisa divisaBase;
    private Dictionary<Divisa, double> ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase;

    public ConversorDivisas(Divisa divisaBase)
    {
        this.divisaBase = divisaBase;
        this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase = new Dictionary<Divisa, double>();
    }

    public Divisa DivisaBase
    {
        get
        {
            return this.divisaBase;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<Divisa, double> RatiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase = value;
        }
    }

    public Boolean aniadirNuevaDivisa(Divisa divisaAAniadir, double ratio)
    {
        Boolean res = true;
        try
        {
            this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.Add(divisaAAniadir, ratio);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public Boolean eliminarDivisa(Divisa divisaAEliminar)
    {
        return this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.Remove(divisaAEliminar);
    }

    public Boolean cambiarRatioDivisa(Divisa divisa, double ratio)
    {
        Boolean res = this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.ContainsKey(divisa);
        if (res)
        {
            this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.Remove(divisa);
            this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.Add(divisa, ratio);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public ICollection<Divisa> obtenerTodasLasDivisasQueTieneElConversorDeDivisas()
    {
        return this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.Keys;
    }

    public double cambiarTantaCantidadDeUnaDivisaAOtra(double cantidad, Divisa entrada, Divisa salida)
    {
        double res = 0.0;
        if (entrada.Equals(this.divisaBase)&&entrada.Equals(salida))
        {
            res = cantidad;
        }
        else{
            if (entrada.Equals(this.divisaBase))
            {
                res = cantidad / this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase[salida];
            }
            else
            {
                if (salida.Equals(this.divisaBase))
                {
                    res = cantidad * this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase[entrada];
                }
                else
                {
                    res = (cantidad * this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase[entrada]) / this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase[salida];
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public Boolean comprobarSiSePuedeCambiarDeUnaDivisaAOtra(Divisa entrada, Divisa salida)
    {
        return (this.divisaBase.Equals(entrada)||this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.ContainsKey(entrada)) && (this.divisaBase.Equals(salida) || this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.ContainsKey(salida));
    }

    public Boolean contieneLaDivisaDada(Divisa divisa)
    {
        return this.ratiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.ContainsKey(divisa);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Divisa euro = new Divisa("Euro");
Divisa dolar = new Divisa("Dólar");
Divisa libra = new Divisa("Libra");
Divisa libra1 = new Divisa("Libra");
Divisa yen = new Divisa("Yen");
ConversorDivisas cd = new ConversorDivisas(euro);
cd.aniadirNuevaDivisa(dolar, 0.868614);
cd.aniadirNuevaDivisa(libra, 1.13739);
cd.aniadirNuevaDivisa(yen, 0.00764246);
Console.WriteLine(cd.RatiosDeCadaDivisaRespectoALaBase.ContainsKey(new Divisa("Libra"))); //tells false
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have been said that you don't need to implement IEqualityComparator in divisa and override gethashcode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrC0p.png)

I am looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Best regards,
WaterKnight

Comment: Hi @WaterKnight, welcome to StackOverflow!
Would you please post the source code for the ConversorDivisas class?

Comment: @GabrielRainha I updated the post and added the code of ConversorDivisas.

Comment: You *do* need to override `GetHashCode()`, don't know where you got the idea that `EqualityComparer.Default` would work without that.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't done implementing `IEquatable<T>` yet.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) has an additional requirement:

> If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode()` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `Equals(T)` method.

If you skip this step, you'll run into misbehavior.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but it says that if you extend of IEquatable<T> you should implement these two methods not IEquatable<Divisa>. Maybe I am misundertsanding something. And what is the correct implementation for my Divisa class to get the result that I am expecting.

Comment: @WaterKnight: Well I don't know what line in the documentation is making you think that, but the portion I quoted is "also" -- very clear that you do both.

Comment: What is a good implementation for hashcode then, so i get the result that i am expecting?

Comment: If it just has a string, use the string's hash code.

Answer (score -1):

if you change

```
.ContainsKey(new Divisa("Libra"))
```

to

```
.ContainsKey(libra)
```

your code would work. You are currently creating a new Object-Instance of your Class Divisa which is obviously not in the dictionary. By changing it to pass in the actual instance of the already created object you will find it.

Hope this helps you further!

Cheers

---

Further i would also recomend you to start using the language Feature "auto property". This example of code can be rewritten to:

```
private Divisa divisaBase;
public Divisa DivisaBase
{
    get
    {
       return this.divisaBase;
    }
}
```

the following:

```
public Divisa DivisaBase { get; private set; }
```

which makes your source code shorter and easy readable.

Comment: I know that this would solve the problem, but i would like .ContainsKey(new Divisa("Libra")) to return true. I would like to get the same result as of a Map in Java with his key is an object with equals redefined so it doesn't compare just the reference of the object. I waant to return true if the two objects has the same string attribute.

Comment: .ContainsKey(new Devisa("Libra")) just wont return true in this constellation. What you could do would be to change the key of your dictionary to be a string (e.g. Libra, Dólar, Euro etc.)

Comment: I thought that I could get the same result as in java.

Comment: I understand you, but i do not fully see the benefit of making a collection index based on a object with contains a string. And then when querying the collection based on keys to instantiate complete new objects.

Comment: We need this exercise to be well designed and maybe in future expand the attributes of divisa but keep the equal being with its name. And querying with new instannties that are identicaly the same.

Comment: Ok fine as you please